# How to copy records from table1 in db1 to table2 in db2

Tags: mysql, insert, copy

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

The above is a simple way to copy EVERYTHING from table1 TO table2.

However I have a couple of problems,

1. The two tables are in two different database
2. I don't want to copy everything, just the extra records that exist in table1

For example.

```
Table 1
-----------
id | name | age

1 | Mike | 30

2 | Ross | 28


Table 2
-----------
id | name | age

1 | Mike | 30
```

Now I just want to copy the row with id 2 onto table2 as row 1 already exists.

P.S. Is there a way that I can modify the age (example, multiply the age by 1.5) to alter the records in table2?

Comment: INSERT INTO paste
SELECT id, age FROM copy
WHERE copy.id > (SELECT id FROM paste ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

I have already come up with the above code to copy only the records which are not in table2 (table1=copy and table2=paste). I hope this is the most efficient way to do it. However, I am still struggling with modifying the data in the process of copying them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (id, name,age)

SELECT Table1.Id,Table1.name,Table1.age FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.id=Table2.id)
WHERE Table2.id IS NULL
```

If you need to modify `age` field during insertion just change `age` to `age*1.5` in the SELECT list.

Comment: Hi, I came back to know whether it will possibly work with the tables being on two different databases situated in two different servers?

Answer (score 0):

**To copy data from one table to another :**

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 (COL1, COL2, COL3) SELECT COL1, COL4, COL7 FROM TABLE1To copy data from one database to another :



USE `old_database`;

 INSERT INTO `new_database`.`new_table`(`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)

 SELECT `old_table`.`column2`, `old_table`.`column3`, `old_table`.`column5`

 FROM `old_table
```